# PHP how to create php pages from files

Tags: php

So, this will be very basic question.

I am new to php.

So, let say my domain name is `example.com`. And I have 4 php files for 4 different pages:

```
intro.php for example.com/intro

welcome.php for example.com/welcome

computer.php for example.com/computer

phone.php for example.com/phone
```

The question that I have is that how do I create different children url based on the php files that I have? So that appropriate files will be called when an user visits the url.

What is the structure?

Thanks

Comment: Look up .htaccess to overwrite your urls

Comment: Do we know what is the web server? In short you must define rewrite rule(s).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need somthing like routing?

See this link here for a start or:

http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

a framework would do the routing for you if you don't want to do it yourself.

Did that help you?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\\.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

You still have to change all the links on your site to point to the new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would to make a html form with a method "get" that way you submit a form with a query string.
Say you have a web app which has articles, you can have a page that processes the articles, say, "single_post.php". 
From index.php you can have

```
<form action="single_post.php" method="get" ><input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php $key ?>" /><button type="submit">Read article</button></form>
```

In single_post.php you get:

```
<?php $key = $_GET['key'] ?>
```

Then you can use php to manipulate the page as you see fit.